# Actions SDK/Dialogflow waiting longer than 10 sec for User Input

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am currently developing my first app for Google Assistant using `Dialogflow`. Now if I say nothing for 10 seconds, the intent is repeated. After this happens 3 times, the intent is closed. That's the case with my Google Home devices. For my smartphone, the Assistant waits several hours for the answer. I have already read several articles on this topic, but I have not been able to solve the issue.

What are the settings for the Google Assistant to wait longer on Google Home devices?

I found the function `mic_waiting_time_seconds` under [InputPrompt](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/webhook#InputPrompt). However, I believe that this is only for Actions SDK. If so, can one give me an example of how to best integrate that?

Or do you have other ideas on how to do that best?

Example dialog for my app:

> GA: Ok, now cut the tomato and cucumber small.
>
> (more than 10 seconds later)
>
> A: Alright, next step

Comment: Right now Assistant apps are meant to be conversational, so there is not much support for waiting indefinitely for commands.